# Please install android target 19 (the android newest sdk) when adding android platform in Cordova

Tags: java, android, cordova

When I am going to add android platform then I am getting this error

> please install android target 19 (the android newest sdk). make sure
>   you have the latest android tools installed as well. Run "androir"
>   from your command line to install update any missing sdk or tools

while in C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\tools
android.bat i have checked that there is installed things are:
android sdk tools 23.0.2
android sdk platform tool 20
android sdk build tools 20
android sdk build tools 19
and android 4.3 (API 18)'s SDK Platform and Samples for sdk installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install Android 4.4.2 ( API 19) SDK platform and not SDK build tools.
See the below image. Do you have the things marked in **RED** as in the below image **installed**?
[image]

Comment: SDK Platform wasn't installed now i am going to install(only SDK) it and Documentaation for android SDK was not available.